# Is it possible to include an mp4 file in the article class?

Tags: article, video

I've seen answers on this site for how to include mp4 files in the `beamer` class, but I was wondering if it was possible to do the same thing in the `article` class.

Ideally, the clip would play in the PDF, but another possibility is that there would be a clickable link that pops open a video player.

Comment: All these methods are class-agnostic. It is just that presentations are the most frequent document type that calls for embedded animations. For playing multimedia on clicking a link, try one of the `attachfile2` or `embedfile` packages.

Comment: You could also do `\href{run:path/file.mp4}{\includegraphics{image}}` to make a clickable image that would open the video. Mind, this would not work in ALL pdf viewers